# How to set different log levels for each type of exception in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, exception, logging

I was assigned to find 'laravel-way' of how to set different log levels for each type of exception. 
For example SmsServiceException should report to notice level, while PaymentServiceException - to some custom level. 
From Laravel docs it seems that recommended approach is to modify report method of App\Exceptions\Handler as this way:

```
if ($e instanceof SmsServiceException) {
    $loggingLevel = 'notice';
} elseif ($e instanceof PaymentServiceException) {
    $loggingLevel = 'custom';
}

$logger->{$loggingLevel}(
    $e->getMessage(),
    array_merge(
        $this->exceptionContext($e),
        $this->context(),
        ['exception' => $e]
    )
);
```

But I need to find another way. 
Something like adding a logLevel property in every exception and then in handler:

```
$logger->{$e->logLevel}(
    $e->getMessage(),
    array_merge(
        $this->exceptionContext($e),
        $this->context(),
        ['exception' => $e]
    )
);
```

Or pass log level as a param to exception constructor:

```
throw new SmsServiceException('message', $logLevel);
```

Can anyone recommend any 'laravel-way' method other than the first one from above?